# Get value of multiple rating bars and set a limit on how many stars can be used

Tags: android, android-fragments, ratingbar

I am working on a project with fragments where I have 4 rating bars (with four stars each) and the user can only use up 10 "stars" combined from all the rating bars.

I am trying to add up the values right now, but even that doesn't work. I want to be able to add up all the values, and then restrict how many values can be set throughout all the ratings.

FragmentRatings.java:

```
public class FramentRatings extends Fragment{
    RatingBar rbStrength, rbIntellect, rbWisdom, rbDexterity;
    TextView tvPointSpent;
    float pointsS, pointsI, pointsW, pointsD, total;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ratings, container, false);

        rbStrength = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.strengthRating);
        rbIntellect = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.intellectRating);
        rbWisdom = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.wisdomRating);
        rbDexterity = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.dexterityRating);


        tvPointSpent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvPointsSpend);

        rbStrength.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                tvPointSpent.setText(""+rbStrength.getRating());
                pointsS = rbStrength.getRating();
            }
        });

        rbIntellect.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                //tvPointSpent.setText(""+rbIntellect.getRating());
                pointsI = rbIntellect.getRating();
            }
        });

        rbWisdom.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                //tvPointSpent.setText(""+rbStrength.getRating());
                pointsW = rbWisdom.getRating();
            }
        });

        rbDexterity.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                //tvPointSpent.setText(""+rbStrength.getRating());
                pointsD = rbDexterity.getRating();
            }
        });

        total = pointsD + pointsI + pointsS + pointsW;

        tvPointSpent.setText(""+pointsS);

        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_ratings.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStrength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="59dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:text="Strength:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIntellect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvStrength"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvStrength"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/intellectRating"
        android:text="Intellect:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWisdom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvIntellect"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvIntellect"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wisdomRating"
        android:text="Wisdom:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="141dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="141dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/intellectRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/strengthRating"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/wisdomRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/intellectRating"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/intellectRating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/intellectRating"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/dexterityRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/wisdomRating"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wisdomRating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wisdomRating"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:numStars="4"
        android:rating="0"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDexterity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvIntellect"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvIntellect"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dexterityRating"
        android:text="Dexterity:"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPoints"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDexterity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvDexterity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dexterityRating"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Points left to spend: "
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPointsSpend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvPoints"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvPoints"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvPoints"
        android:text="10"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[Picture of the rating bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEPqi.png)

Comment: Not an Android developer, but there doesn't seem to be an onChanging Event to capture before/after. So what I'd probably do is create "current" values for each of your stats. Using strength being changed for example, I'd take currentWisdom + currentIntellect + currentDexterity + rbStrength.getRating() and if it is greater than 10, I either: a) rbStrength.setRating(currentStrength) // reset or b) rbStrength.setRating(10 - currentWisdom - currentIntellect - currentDexterity) // max remaining I can set it. If it is <= 10, currentStrength = rbStrength.getRating()

Answer (score 0):

Might have got the logic wrong but shouldn't the line:

tvPointSpent.setText(""+pointsS);

be:

tvPointSpent.setText(String.valueOf(total));

Answer (score 0):

I am probably very late, But

One quick fix I would suggest is `pointsS = ratingBar.getRating();`
or`pointsS = rating;` and like this for rest, since these parameters in the function `onRatingChanged(...)` are which fetch the changed and final values.